# Enabling CORS support to a REST API

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, cors, azure-table-storage

I am trying to find out why many developers disable CORS by default in their REST API offerings? Is security the main concern? From the [W3C wiki article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) on CORS support, it looks like it is fairly simple to add CORS support (add a header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** with value '*' on the server)

I recently ran into issues when trying to write a simple javascript only app to access Azure tables and other Rest APIs like the ones from [Panoptix](https://developer.panoptix.com/) and ProductWIKI. They had some great REST APIs but wouldn't allow CORS. Azure tables in specific has a stringent authentication process associated with their REST API calls and in spite of that it wouldn't let CORS (at least for the moment).

I would like to hear from developers and Admins of RESTFul APIs on their reasoning behind enabling/disabling CORS for your API offerings? Is security/traffic/compatibility the main concern or is there anything more to it?

Comment: I'm interested in this question from the server side. For service APIs I've set up, I usually add CORS, just because it opens the door to playing with the API from the browser. But I've wondered what the security considerations are. My perspective is that CORS only affects browsers, and only defeats their same-origin policy, so a hacker could throw up a simple proxy server and beat CORS anyway. But I'd be interested in the attitude toward CORS from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I make Web services I leave off CORS because it is the default setting and only add it if the project requires public browser access to our services. Why same-origin policy is the default is a different question. I've never seen the advantage in disallowing Ajax access from other domains.

Comment: By "public browser access", do you mean access with/without any authentication. Is there anything that I should consider while allowing CORS for an REST API that requires authentication?

Comment: Authentication would be important but know that Web services that are not CORS-enabled are still publicly useable, just not by commercial Web browsers. Same-origin policy is nothing but a weak garden gate and offers little in real security. My greater concerns when making an external Web service would be improving clarity, documentation, versioning and scalability.

Comment: [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is a big concern for web applications running from the browser. If we didn't have Same-origin policy, we'd be able to call web services on your behalf, using your cookies on another web app while you browse our web app.

Comment: CSRF is an existing problem because you can use off-site JavaScript as the attribute for the `src` attribute of a script tag. Cross-origin Ajax does not introduce any new security vulnerabilities.